# Rails select_tag with multiple value only send first one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have made a filter form with a `select_tag` `multiple`. When I submit my form, the params I get are `"category_id"=>"3"` (I want an array :/), and the url is like : `http://localhost:5000/wods?category_id=1&category_id=3`. I put a `debugger` on submitting form: `$('form').serialize()` returns `"category_id%5B%5D=3&category_id%5B%5D=4"`, so the params are set correctly, but not in the controller.

If I enter in the url `http://localhost:5000/wods?category_id[]=1&category_id[]=3`, it send the correct params `"category_id"=>["3","1"]`.

What I doing wrong :/ ? Here is my code :

```
<%= form_with url: sessions_update_path, method: :get, local: true, id: 'filters' do %>
  <%= select_tag "category_id[]",
              options_for_select(Category.all.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id), session[:categories]),
              multiple: true,
              class: 'select2',
              include_blank: true %>
  <%= submit_tag t('actions.filter'), class: 'btn mr-10' %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you very much for your help !

**UPDATE :**

Ok, I figured out what happened. I have a `before_action` which call `encode_www_form` on my url params which does not handle multiple values params. I will find a workaround to this method.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you permitted an array in your controller params ?

Comment: I have updated my message. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad that you found a solution, and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Still noob using the "active" part of Stack Overflow. I just saw your message @askprod. Thank you for the welcoming message :) !